# How to make circle of text in latex?

Tags: graphics, color, text

How to make circle of text in latex? Seee the picture below. How to make it in generally?

Thanks for some ideas.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems like a do-it-for-me question. Please post what you've got so far (TikZ code, pstricks code, ...) as a MWE.

Comment: I would like to point out that the underlying structure of such a circle is actually a tree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Steps**:

1. background color:  draw the coloured wheel in the background
2. construct wheel: draw lines and circles above
3. add text: input text positioning

[image]

*Coloring*: Draw the path of the different parts. With `\usepackage{xcolor}` you could use own colors liek `\definecolor{darkbrown}{RGB}{108,86,0},
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{183,0,19}`. Also you could use the option `opacity`.

Inner: radius 0 to 3, single parts/ color => `\path`

```
\path[fill,darkbrown,opacity=0.7] (10:0) -- (10:3) -- ([shift=(10:3cm)]0,0)arc (10:50:3cm) -- (50:3) -- (50:0); ...
```

Middle: radius 3 to 6, multiple parts/ color => `\foreach` loop

```
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {10,20,...,40}{
\path[fill,brown,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}
```

Every part has an angle of `10` -> `evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)`. So `\xi` is defined with `\ang+10` and represents the end of one single element.

Outer: radius 6 to 9, multiple parts/ color => also `\foreach` loop is used like above.

*Construct the wheel:* With predifend angles of `10,50,130,190,230,310`(inner,#6 elements), `0,10,...,350`(middle,#36 elements) and `5,10,...,360`(outer,#72 elements) you can create your wheel.

```
% inner
\foreach \ang in {10,50,130,190,230,310}{
    \draw [black,thick] (\ang:0) -- (\ang:3);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);

% middle
\foreach \ang in {0,10,...,350} {
    \draw [black,thick] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (6cm);

% outer
\foreach \ang in {5,10,...,360} {
    \draw [black,thick] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (9cm);
```

*text:* With(`\usepackage{pgfmath}` you could define a data array, per single ring,  like this one here:

```
\def\namesInner{{"string A","string B","string C"}
```

Then you could add the text like this:

```
    \draw [style01] (\ang:1.5) node[rotate=\ang]
      {\pgfmathparse{\names[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
```

This could happen inside a loop, the rotations depends on the textposition -> if conditions (like `\ifnum\ang<271`) are helpful.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{style01/.style={ font=\bfseries\normalsize\sffamily}}

\def\names{{"DISGUST","ANGER","FEAR","SURPRISE","HAPPY","SAD"}}

\def\namesTwo{{"GUILTY","AVOIANCE","AWFUL","DISAPPOINTED","DISAPPROVAL","CRITICAL","DISTANT","FRUSTRATED",
"AGGRESIVE","MAD","HATEFUL","THREATENED","HURT","HUMILIATED","REJECTED","SUBMISSIVE",
"INSECURE","ANXIOUS","SCARED","STARTLED","CONFUSED","AMAZED","EXCITED","JOYFUL",
"INTERESTED","PROUD","ACCEPTED","POWERFUL","PEACEFUL","INTIMATE","OPTIMISTIC","BORED",
"LONELY","DEPRESSED","DESPAIR","ABANDONED"}}

\def\namesThree{{"ASHAMED","REMORESFUL","HESITANT","AVERSION","DETESTABLE","REVULSION","REVOLTED","REPUGNANT",
"LOATHING","JUDGMENTAL","SARCASTIC","SKEPTICAL","SUSPICIOUS","WITHDRAWN","IRRITATED","INFURIATED",
"HOSTILE","PROVOKED","ENRAGED","FURIOUS","VIOLATED","RESENTFUL","JEALOUS","INSECURE",
"DEVASTATED","EMBARRASSED","RIDICULED","DISRESPECTED","ALIENATED","INADEQUATE","INSIGNIFICANT","WORTHLESS",
"INFERIOR","INADEQUATE","WORRIED","OVERWHELMED","FERIGHTENED","TERRIFIED","SHOCKED","DISMAYED","DISILLUSONED",
"PERPLEXED","ASTONISHED","AWE","EAGER","ENERGETIC","LIBERATED","ESTATIC","AMUSED","INQUISITIVE",
"IMPORTANT","CONFIDENT","RESPECTED","FULLFILLED","COURAGEOUS","PROVOCATIVE","LOVING","HOPEFUL","SENSITIVE",
"PLAYFUL","OPEN","INSPIRED","INDIFFERENT","APATHETIC","ISOLATED","ABANDONED","EMPTY","INFERIOR",
"VULNERABLE","POWERLESS","VICTIMIZED","IGNORED"}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{darkbrown}{RGB}{108,86,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{183,0,19}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,154,0}
\definecolor{darkorange}{RGB}{224,85,0}
\definecolor{darkyellow}{RGB}{255,255,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,29,207}
%\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Coloring:  Background
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {230,240,...,300}{ % OR
%\foreach \ang [count=\i from 24, evaluate=\i as \xi using int(\i*10)] in {230,240,...,300}{

% inner
\path[fill,darkbrown,opacity=0.7] (10:0) -- (10:3) -- ([shift=(10:3cm)]0,0)arc (10:50:3cm) -- (50:3) -- (50:0);
\path[fill,darkred,opacity=1] (50:0) -- (50:3) -- ([shift=(50:3cm)]0,0)arc (50:130:3cm) -- (130:3) -- (130:0);
\path[fill,darkgreen,opacity=1] (130:0) -- (130:3) -- ([shift=(130:3cm)]0,0)arc (130:190:3cm) -- (190:3) -- (190:0);
\path[fill,darkorange,opacity=0.7] (190:0) -- (190:3) -- ([shift=(190:3cm)]0,0)arc (190:230:3cm) -- (230:3) -- (230:0);
\path[fill,darkyellow,opacity=0.7] (230:0) -- (230:3) -- ([shift=(230:3cm)]0,0)arc (230:310:3cm) -- (310:3) -- (310:0);
\path[fill,darkblue,opacity=0.7] (310:0) -- (310:3) -- ([shift=(310:3cm)]0,0)arc (310:370:3cm) -- (370:3) -- (370:0);

% middle (Parts:36)
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {10,20,...,40}{
\path[fill,brown,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {50,60,...,120}{
\path[fill,red,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {130,140,...,180}{
\path[fill,green,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {190,200,...,220}{
\path[fill,orange,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {230,240,...,300}{
\path[fill,yellow,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+10)] \ang in {310,320,...,360}{
\path[fill,blue,opacity=0.5] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6) -- ([shift=(\ang:6cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:6cm) -- (\xi:6) -- (\xi:3);
}

% outer
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+5)] \ang in {10,15,...,45}{
\path[fill,brown,opacity=0.3] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9) -- ([shift=(\ang:9cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:9cm) -- (\xi:9) -- (\xi:6);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+5)] \ang in {50,55,...,125}{
\path[fill,red,opacity=0.3] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9) -- ([shift=(\ang:9cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:9cm) -- (\xi:9) -- (\xi:6);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+5)] \ang in {130,135,...,185}{
\path[fill,green,opacity=0.3] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9) -- ([shift=(\ang:9cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:9cm) -- (\xi:9) -- (\xi:6);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+5)] \ang in {190,195,...,225}{
\path[fill,orange,opacity=0.3] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9) -- ([shift=(\ang:9cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:9cm) -- (\xi:9) -- (\xi:6);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+5)] \ang in {230,235,...,305}{
\path[fill,yellow,opacity=0.3] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9) -- ([shift=(\ang:9cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:9cm) -- (\xi:9) -- (\xi:6);
}
\foreach[evaluate=\xi using int(\ang+5)] \ang in {310,315,...,365}{
\path[fill,blue,opacity=0.3] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9) -- ([shift=(\ang:9cm)]0,0)arc (\ang:\xi:9cm) -- (\xi:9) -- (\xi:6);
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Draw a lines and circle:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% inner
\foreach \ang in {10,50,130,190,230,310}{
    \draw [black,thick] (\ang:0) -- (\ang:3);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);

% middle
\foreach \ang in {0,10,...,350} {
    \draw [black,thick] (\ang:3) -- (\ang:6);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (6cm);

% outer
\foreach \ang in {5,10,...,360} {
    \draw [black,thick] (\ang:6) -- (\ang:9);
}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (9cm); 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Add text:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% inner
\foreach \ang [count=\i from 1, evaluate=\i as \xi using int(\i-1)] in {30,90,160,210,270,340}{%{-20,30,90,160,210,270}{
\ifnum\ang<91
\draw [style01] (\ang:1.5) node[rotate=\ang]
  {\pgfmathparse{\names[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\else
\ifnum\ang<271
\draw [style01] (\ang:1.5) node[rotate=\ang-180]
  {\pgfmathparse{\names[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\else
\draw [style01] (\ang:1.5) node[rotate=\ang-360]
  {\pgfmathparse{\names[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\fi
\fi
}

%% middle
\foreach \ang [count=\i from 1, evaluate=\i as \xi using int(\i-1)] in {5,15,...,355}{
\ifnum\ang<91
\draw [style01] (\ang:4.5) node[rotate=\ang]
  {\pgfmathparse{\namesTwo[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\else
\ifnum\ang<271
\draw [style01] (\ang:4.5) node[rotate=\ang-180]
  {\pgfmathparse{\namesTwo[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\else
\draw [style01] (\ang:4.5) node[rotate=\ang-360]
  {\pgfmathparse{\namesTwo[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\fi
\fi
}

% outer
\foreach \ang [count=\i from 1, evaluate=\i as \xi using int(\i-1)] in {2,7,...,357}{
\ifnum\ang<90
\draw [style01] (\ang+0.5:7.5) node[rotate=\ang+0.5]
  {\pgfmathparse{\namesThree[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\else
\ifnum\ang<270
\draw [style01] (\ang+0.5:7.5) node[rotate=\ang+0.5-180]
  {\pgfmathparse{\namesThree[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\else
\draw [style01] (\ang+0.5:7.5) node[rotate=\ang+0.5-360]
  {\pgfmathparse{\namesThree[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
\fi
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to ask: Are the words available for easy copy/paste or did you type them in manually?

Comment: @Johannes_B I add them manually. Now you could copy and paste the three definitions (\def\names, (\def\namesTwo and \def\namesThree)

Comment: Oh wow. Unfortunately i cannot upvote twice. What a job.

Answer (score 4):

The `transform shape` key in `tikz` is probably the easiest way. Draw the coloured wheel in the background and then add the writing as:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={transform shape}]
\draw[rotate=10] (1,0) node{disgust};
\draw[rotate=70] (1,0) node{Anger};
\draw[rotate=130] (1,0) node[rotate=180] {Fear};
\draw[rotate=190] (1,0) node[rotate=180] {Surprise};
\draw[rotate=250] (1,0) node {Happy};
\draw[rotate=310] (1,0) node {Sad};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this framework, you need to rotate with the `rotate=` key, otherwise the nodes are left untouched. This should give a sufficient starter for finishing your picture.

[image: The inner lining of the wheel]

Answer (score 2):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

First, the colors are stored in the list `\WCcolors` using the package [listofitems](https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems).

The color is determined by the angle given by `\WCmidangle`. In the key `slices style`, a number is determined depending on this angle. Then `\WCcolor` is defined as the corresponding element of the list `\WCcolors`.

The rotation of the wheel data is determined with the key `wheel data style`.

Each ring is placed in a separate `\wheelchart`.

For the first `\wheelchart`, the values are given by the first variable. For the second and third `\wheelchart`, the key `value=1` is used so that the angle of each slice is the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\readlist\WCcolors{darkbrown,darkred,darkgreen,darkorange,darkyellow,darkblue}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\definecolor{darkbrown}{RGB}{108,86,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{183,0,19}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,154,0}
\definecolor{darkorange}{RGB}{224,85,0}
\definecolor{darkyellow}{RGB}{255,255,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,29,207}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  slices style={
    /utils/exec={
      \pgfmathparse{
        \WCmidangle<10?6:
        (\WCmidangle<50?1:
        (\WCmidangle<130?2:
        (\WCmidangle<190?3:
        (\WCmidangle<230?4:
        (\WCmidangle<310?5:
        6
        )))))
      }
      \edef\WCcolor{\WCcolors[\pgfmathresult]}
    },
    \WCcolor!\opacity,
    draw=black
  },
  start angle=10,
  wheel data pos=0.5,
  wheel data style={rotate={(1-int(Mod({1.5-\WCmidangle/180},2)))*180+\WCmidangle}}
}
\def\opacity{70}
\wheelchart[
  radius={0}{3},
  wheel data=\WCvarB
]{4/DISGUST,8/ANGER,6/FEAR,4/SURPRISE,8/HAPPY,6/SAD}
\def\opacity{50}
\wheelchart[
  radius={3}{6},
  value=1,
  wheel data=\WCvarA
]{AVOIANCE,AWFUL,DISAPPOINTED,DISAPPROVAL,CRITICAL,DISTANT,FRUSTRATED,AGGRESIVE,MAD,HATEFUL,THREATENED,HURT,HUMILIATED,REJECTED,SUBMISSIVE,INSECURE,ANXIOUS,SCARED,STARTLED,CONFUSED,AMAZED,EXCITED,JOYFUL,INTERESTED,PROUD,ACCEPTED,POWERFUL,PEACEFUL,INTIMATE,OPTIMISTIC,BORED,LONELY,DEPRESSED,DESPAIR,ABANDONED,GUILTY}
\def\opacity{30}
\wheelchart[
  radius={6}{9},
  value=1,
  wheel data=\WCvarA
]{HESITANT,AVERSION,DETESTABLE,REVULSION,REVOLTED,REPUGNANT,LOATHING,JUDGMENTAL,SARCASTIC,SKEPTICAL,SUSPICIOUS,WITHDRAWN,IRRITATED,INFURIATED,HOSTILE,PROVOKED,ENRAGED,FURIOUS,VIOLATED,RESENTFUL,JEALOUS,INSECURE,DEVASTATED,EMBARRASSED,RIDICULED,DISRESPECTED,ALIENATED,INADEQUATE,INSIGNIFICANT,WORTHLESS,INFERIOR,INADEQUATE,WORRIED,OVERWHELMED,FERIGHTENED,TERRIFIED,SHOCKED,DISMAYED,DISILLUSONED,PERPLEXED,ASTONISHED,AWE,EAGER,ENERGETIC,LIBERATED,ESTATIC,AMUSED,INQUISITIVE,IMPORTANT,CONFIDENT,RESPECTED,FULLFILLED,COURAGEOUS,PROVOCATIVE,LOVING,HOPEFUL,SENSITIVE,PLAYFUL,OPEN,INSPIRED,INDIFFERENT,APATHETIC,ISOLATED,ABANDONED,EMPTY,INFERIOR,VULNERABLE,POWERLESS,VICTIMIZED,IGNORED,ASHAMED,REMORESFUL}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```