# How to create Circular classification taxonomies in Latex?

Tags: circles, pgf-pie

How I can make the following Circular taxonomy in Latex. It’s for a literature review. I can draw this in Microsoft Visio or other software but I want add the references in the text as well in each circle.

Kindly, provide your help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us what you try so far?

Comment: I've seen this diagram style used for thoroughbred sire lines, e.g., http://nebula.wsimg.com/4086ac5749c1429bdfcf6fcf3499bd30?AccessKeyId=106D5AF965FBF29B190D&disposition=0&alloworigin=1

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I prefer to see a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem, next time. It will be much easier when we have a starting point of a mwe. It contains compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Possibly related : [How to make circle of text in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370870/how-to-make-circle-of-text-in-latex#comment915912_370870) (which does not have a full solution yet)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\usepackage{tikz}` and create the circular taxonomy with simple circles and lines.

1. Draw circles wih different size:
   `\draw[thick,black] (\r,0) arc (0:360:\r);`
2. Draw radial lines : `\draw [red] (\ang * 360/5:1) -- (\ang * 360/5:4.5);`

   - line direction is `\ang*360/5` / `\ang*72degree` (0=right,90=top)
   - length: from radius 1 to 4.5
3. Adding text:

   - in center: `\node[style01] at (0cm,0cm) {Text};`
   - on circle: `\draw [style01] (\ang * 180 / 2.5:\r) node[rotate=-10] {Text B};`

To rotate the text inside a node you could use the option `rotate`. With `\tikzset{style01/.style={ font=\bfseries\normalsize\sffamily}}` you can define your own textstyle (bold, sans serif,...).

**Solution:**

[image]

**MWE** ([minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{style01/.style={ font=\bfseries\normalsize\sffamily}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
 \foreach \ang in {0.8,1.8,...,4.8} {
   \draw [red] (\ang * 360/5:1) -- (\ang * 360/5:4.5);
 }

\foreach \r in {1,2,2.5,3.5,4.5} {
\draw[thick,black] (\r,0) arc (0:360:\r);
}

\foreach \ang in {1.3,2.3,...,5.3} {
  \foreach \r in {1.5} {
  \draw [style01] (\ang * 180 / 2.5:\r) node[rotate=-10] {Text B};
  }
}
\node[style01] at (0cm,0cm) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```